# isdigit() unexpected behaviour?

Tags: c++, c

Why is the `isdigit` not working as expected. i am trying to check if the input is a digit or not. If the input is digit, then print `True` else `False`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main()
{
    int h;
    printf("Height: ");
    scanf("%d", &h);
    if (isdigit(h))
        printf("True");
    else
        printf("False");
}
```

But it returns `False` always.

**Input:**

Height: Foo

Comment: Isdigit tests the char code not if its an int

Comment: I want to check whether the input is number or not. How to do that ?

Comment: Just check scanf return val

Comment: Your program is functioning as expected. The string "Foo" is not a digit neither does it contain one

Answer (score 5):

Because your expectations are incorrect. isdigit() is called on a character to see if it contains a decimal digit, '0'-'9'. You are calling it on an int which is already a binary value.

Comment: How to check if the input is not a character ?

Comment: @rcomp Cease using `scanf()` and try a sane function, such as `fgets()`, for getting user input. Then validate it (e. g. using `strpbrk()`).

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong understand about function `isdigit`. the input of this function is char.
so you can change to this:

```
char h;
printf("Height: ");
scanf("%c", &h);
```

Comment: "... about function isdigit, the input of this function is char." --> The input to `isdigit()` is an `int`, not `char`.  The valid range is `EOF, [0...UCHAR_MAX]`.  This differs from `char` when `char` is _signed_.